# Redshift WLM: If super user is added to automatic WLM query group then how many slots would be given to that query group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have created a WLM query group named ETL and have added 2 super users in that group. I am using automatic WLM, So not changing any concurrency related settings.

I am not clear about one thing that how many number of slots would be assignedand to this "ETL" group since it contains 2 super users?

As per the AWS documentation super user will have separate queue but what if the super users are part of other WLM group(ETL in this case).

When I run this query for ETL WLM `select * from stl_wlm_query`.  In the result its shows slot_count as 1, ideally it should be 5 but same WLM group is also running 5 queries in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two different concepts are being confused here.  Users that have superuser ability and the superuser queue.  The only way a query runs in the superuser queue is if the user is a superuser AND they have set the property "query_group" to 'superuser'.  See - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/cm-c-wlm-queue-assignment-rules.html

So your superuser queries won't run in the superuser queue unless they set query_group like - "set query_group to 'superuser';" in their session.  If this is done then their queries will run in the superuser queue.